# Django Multi Tenant Schemas Media Files Path

Tags: django

I am using Django with Multi Tenant Schemas. Everything is working well on production, but I am having an issue with image media Path.

My web server is an Apache2 installed on Ubuntu 18.04, in the site configuration file I have:

'''

```
ServerName qibot.com.br
ServerAlias tenant1.qibot.com.br tenant2.qibot.com.br tenant3.qibot.com.br
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

Alias /static /var/www/qibot_system/static
<Directory /var/www/qibot_system/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /media /var/www/qibot_system/media/
<Directory /var/www/qibot_system/media/>
Require all granted
</Directory>
...

</VirtualHost>
```

'''

In this way, if the media (image or video) file is requested, django looks for

```
/var/www/qibot_system/media/ instead of 
/var/www/qibot_system/media/tenant1 or 
/var/www/qibot_system/media/tenant2 or 
/var/www/qibot_system/media/tenant3
```

My question is, there is a way to set the variable on the end of /var/www/qibot_system/media/XXXXXXXXX to provide right path to django?

Best Regards